# Send an Email from a SAS program

Tags: sas

Why does this code still send an email when the condition to link to the email
    send cannot get executed?  SASLOG proves condition vale is zero put x=.

```
98   filename outbox email 'dan.xxxxx@zz.com';
99
100  data _null_;
    /* Set variable */
101     x=0;  
102     put x=;
    /* condition cannot be true */
103     if x=1 then do;  
104        link send_email;  /* should only be hit if condition is true */
105     end;
106  return;
107
108  send_email:  /* seems to get executed no matter what */
109     file outbox
110     to=("dan.xxxxx@zzcom")
111     subject="Email test";
112     put "Email test from SAS program";
113     put " ";
114  return;
115  run;

NOTE: The file OUTBOX is:
      E-Mail Access Device

x=0
Message sent
      To:          ("dan.xxxxx@zz.com" )
      Cc:
      Bcc:
      Subject:     Email test
      Attachments:
NOTE: 0 records were written to the file OUTBOX.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           7.22 seconds
      cpu time            0.35 seconds
```

Comment: If an email WAS to be sent, how many emails are you expecting this datastep to send?  Just one?  Or more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more background it's hard to guess exactly how you are planning to do this but I think a cleaner approach would be to:

1. Identify if an email should be sent.
2. Use a datastep within macro code to conditionally send the email.

Step 1:

```
%let send_email = 0;  * WHEN 0 EMAIL WILL NOT BE SENT. WHEN 1 EMAIL WILL BE SENT;

data _null_;
  set mydata;
  if x = 1 then do;
    call symput('send_email',1);
    stop; * LEAVE THE DATASTEP AS SOON AS WE DECIDE AN EMAIL SHOULD BE SENT;
  end;
run;
```

Step 2:

```
%macro send_email;
  %if &send_email eq 1 %then %do;
    filename outbox email 'dan.xxxxx@zz.com';
    data _null_;
      file outbox to=("dan.xxxxx@zzcom") subject="Email test";
      put "Email test from SAS program";
      put " ";
    run;
  %end;
%mend;
%send_email;
```

*EDIT:*  Changed `return` statement in the code to a `stop` statement.

Comment: This option works but I don't understand why my original code did not work.  The Link could only be executed if the condition was true and it could not have been true.  Thank you for your solution.  Dan

Comment: Because 'file' is always 'executed'.  Just like a keep statement, you can't put a keep statement behind an IF (or a LINK or whatever) - if it's between DATA and RUN, it's used.  The act of declaring the file defines and ultimately sends the email - and you cannot conditionally execute that.  You either need to use Bob's workaround, or do it like Rob suggests and conditionally run the entire code.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Yes - Joe's answer correctly explains why your original code would still send the email.

Answer (score 3):

FILE is not a conditionally executable statement but a compile time statement.  Even if no records are output to the file, the file still is created, and in this case presumably the email still gets sent even with no records putting data into it.

See the following:

```
data _null_;
set sashelp.class;
if 0 then do;
    file "c:\temp\temp.txt";
    put age;
end;
run;
```

Even though no records are put to the file, you still see in the log the information about the file being created.

If you're trying to conditionally send email or not send email, you might want to come back with more information about what you're doing so you can get a helpful response as to how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing Joe's more correct answer, I'm completely rewriting mine.

One way you can control email delivery is to use email "directives" rather than options on the `FILE` statement.  For example:

```
filename outbox email;
data _null_;
   x=0;  
   put x=;
   if x=1 then do;  
      link send_email;
      end;
   return;
send_email:  
   file outbox;
   put '!em_to! ( "dan.xxxxx@zzcom" )';
   put '!em_subject! Email Test';

   put "Email test from SAS program";
   put " ";
return;
run;
filename outbox clear;
```

Now when you do this, you will get a SAS Error because a "TO" address was not provided on the original `FILENAME` statement, but it's an error you can ignore.

Comment: I don't like leaving errors, even intentional ones, but you *could* set it up with two different options - one if you have the (true-option) and one if you have the (false option).  If false then send an email to yourself saying "No respondents" or whatever.  Then you get no errors and some useful feedback :)

Comment: @Joe: Normally I'd agree, but I didn't want to confuse the issue by introducing MACRO code in my answer. Rob provided that below.  This is one of the things I really like about SO: different takes on the same question.

Answer (score 0):

```
*Just modified Step 1 to not send emails on weekends - Works great!

%let send_email = 0;  * WHEN 0 EMAIL WILL NOT BE SENT. WHEN 1 EMAIL WILL BE SENT;

data _null_;
   dt=today();
   weekday=weekday(dt);
   if weekday ne 7 or weekday ne 1 then do;
     call symput('send_email',1);
     stop; * LEAVE THE DATASTEP AS SOON AS WE DECIDE AN EMAIL SHOULD BE  SENT;
   end;
```

run;